# MySQL (5.7) error - ERROR 1418 (HY000) when restoring from backup

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This error started to show up this morning when restoring a backup.  This error did not occur on the last run through of restoring a backup (3 weeks ago).

•   10:33:26 AM : ERROR: Job execution error: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. ERROR 1418 (HY000) at line 15089: This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable) Server name: "MYSERVER"
•   10:33:28 AM : ERROR: Job "RESTORE - TR to LOCAL" finished with "1" errors

While binary logging is enabled, this server is not currently in a master / slave setup.

I did add log_bin_trust_function_creators=1; to my.ini but that did not help.